# Smart pills reminder that considers meals as well?

Tags: ios, applications, software-recommendation

I have 5-6 pills that I have to take during the day. I am *amazed* how bad iOS apps for pills are! For example, there is no app that:

reminds me to take pill sometime before and after a meal!

I do not want only to set the time to eg 7am and then to 8am, hoping I will eat at 7:30am. If I eat at 8:30am, I still want to use the app, and to remind me that e.g. 30min from taking the pill has passed and that I can eat now.

I tried 30+ apps, and they all are just simple schedulers, that I could make in google calendar by myself.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE

Lets say I have 2 pills: 1 is taken 30 min before meal and second is taken 30 min after the meal.

The app would send first notification at e.g. 7am. Lets say I have to postpone until 8am, so I take the first pill at 8am. The app timer starts, and it will notify me at 8:30am to eat and then at e.g. 9:15am to take the second pill (assuming i eat for 15 min).

#### Apps found so far that considers meal somehow

- [RX2](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rx2-meds-and-pill-reminder-lite/id796382486?mt=8) - not updated for years, just a list, no checkins.

Comment: How do you expect the app to know when you finally decide to eat?

Comment: @SolarMike from the time I take the first pill. It's ok to have notifications for the first pill before, but timer starts from the moment when I take the first pill

Comment: @SolarMike see update for example

Comment: So, you need to enter your start time then enter subsequent times... an automator script may work if it triggers from your first pill entry time.

Comment: @SolarMike I know I can code that, but I have 6 different pills/times (plus different scheme in 14 days) and I would really love to save time and get an app for that that is already tested and working...

Comment: Why not using Siri and reminders? When you're done eating say: "Hey Siri, remind me to take a pill in 30 minutes"

Comment: Does Siri work if there is no network?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek because i have to remember also the name of the pill etc. Also, my front microphone is not working, so Siri is useless for me :(

Comment: @SolarMike No, Siri requires an Internet connection.